# AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, androidx

Everything was working fine, i did not make any changes, and for two days i'm trying to solve it without any success.
I tried to change target and compile versions but without success
I also upgraded core androidx.core version
I don't have netinfo installed
the thing is that i didn't make any changes, it's like yesterday it's working and today it's not working

```
/Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/79b3ee8c2241218be0a4eb5e4975ee77/core-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

this is the error when i run npx react-native run-android

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/anis/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/79b3ee8c2241218be0a4eb5e4975ee77/core-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```